# Firebase Auth: impossible to clear photoURL?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

It seems like it is impossible to clear a field once it's already set on the user profile? For example, my logged in user does have a photoURL set, now I am trying to clear it by setting it to `nil`.

```swift
let changeRequest = Auth.auth().currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest()
changeRequest?.photoURL = nil
changeRequest?.commitChanges { [weak self] error in
  if let error = error {
    print(error)
    return
  }

  print("photo before reload: \(Auth.auth().currentUser!.photoURL)")

  Auth.auth().currentUser?.reload(completion: { _ in
    print("photo after reload: \(Auth.auth().currentUser!.photoURL)")
  })
}
```

Output:

```
photo before reload: nil
photo after reload: Optional(https://github.com/kevinrenskers.png)
```

And indeed, when restarting the app or even logging out and back in, that old photoURL is still there. I can't find a way to remove a property on the user profile once it's set. What am I missing here?

Comment: If you want to allow the user to change properties of their account, consider instead storing the information in a database rather than trying to change the account in Firebase Authentication.  You can populate the database with initial values from Auth, then just use the database from there on out.

Comment: I've thought about that too, but that *shouldn't* be necessary, right? According to the docs this should simply work.

Comment: I have indeed gone this route: a top level Users collection where I am storing this info. With a snapshot listener so it's updated automatically on all devices as well. Works nicely, still too bad this was necessary.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `changeRequest.photoUrl = nil` you are only changing the value in that instance of `currentUser`, you’re not changing it in Firebase. So when you reload the instance, it reads the unchanged `photoUrl` value from Firebase when reloading another instance of `currentUser`.

To remove the photoUrl, reset it within the `commitChanges` method of `currentUser`

Comment: There is no method `updateProfile`, only updateEmail, updatePassword and updatePhoneNumber. Also this is the way described in the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#update_a_users_profile.

Comment: Yeah sorry, you would call commitChanges and remove the value within the closure

Comment: That goes against the example in the docs I linked to earlier, and against the API docs which specifically states "It is an error to set this property after calling `FIRUserProfileChangeRequest.commitChangesWithCallback:`"

Comment: Just for fun I did try your suggestion, and as expected it doesn't work. In fact, it crashes the app: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid call to setPhotoURL: after commitChangesWithCallback:.'`

Comment: You can’t set a value to nil in Firebase, that’s probably why it’s crashing. You have to remove the value of the photoUrl branch or maybe set the photoUrl to “”. Sorry I usually just set user attributes through a users branch in my database, if you do that you could remove the value

Comment: No, the crash is from updating the property within the block. And an empty string doesn’t work since it needs to be a valid URL (or nil).

Comment: Sorry Kevin, I meant that to be a comment. I mean setting the changeRequest.photoUrl to nil as you originally did, but then call commitChanges afterwards (the maybe load the user again inside the closure to check it worked)